# How do I "regex-quote" a string in XPath

Tags: xpath, xslt, xpath-2.0

I have an XSL template that takes 2 parameters (*text* and *separator*) and calls *tokenize($text, $separator)*.
The problem is, the separator is supposed to be a regex. I have no idea what I get passed as separator string.

In Java I would call Pattern.quote(separator) to get a pattern that matches the exact string, no matter what weird characters it might contain, but I could not find anything like that in XPath.
I could iterate through the string and escape any character that I recognize as a special character with regard to regex.
I could build an iteration with substring-before and do the tokenize that way.
I was wondering if there is an easier, more straightforward way?

Comment: XPath 3 allows the flag `q` e.g. `tokenize($text, $separator, 'q')`, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags, I don't remember whether that was also supported in 2.0.

Comment: And http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html should also help.

Comment: The `q` parameter which @MartinHonnen mentions wasn't in XPath 2.0 https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags I believe. Personally I would probably opt for writing a tiny recursive function calling `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Answer (score 0):

You could escape your separator tokens using the XPath `replace` function to find any character that requires escaping, and precede each occurrence with a `\`. Then you could pass such an escaped token to the XPath `tokenize` function.

Alternatively you could just implement your own `tokenize` stylesheet function, and use the `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions to extract substrings, and recursion to process the full string.